# Powershell stop process using process age behaving wierd

Tags: powershell

My little script works like this

```
$age = read-host "enter age"
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "notepad" -and ($_.starttime).totalminutes -le $age} | Stop-Process (New-TimeSpan -Start (get-process notepad).StartTime).totalminutes
```

If I change the `-le` to `-gt` or `-ge` (which is what I am trying to use) it will not kill the process... I don't really understand why this is not working.

Can anyone share some insights?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but I assume you want to kill the notepad process, which was running for longer than defined number of minutes. In this case you can use such script

```
# Get process
Get-Process | 
# which has the name of notepad and current date minus start date in minutes is less than defined age
Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "notepad" -and ((Get-Date) - $_.starttime).TotalMinutes -gt $age } | 
#Kill the process
Stop-Process
```

The trick here is to get the difference of current date and start date in minutes, which can be achieved like this:

```
((Get-Date) - $_.starttime).TotalMinutes
```

Comment: Hey. Yes that was what I was trying to do. Your tip seemed to have helped! Thanks a lot